# Finding center of a cross hair in image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab

I am trying to find the center of the cross hairs in the below images. Currently I am manually finding it using my mouse to mark the red spots as found in the images. Is there an image processing technique that I could use to automate this process or at least to an extent that the manual work required is reduced?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The red dots you have marked in the second image; Do they represent a complete set of all the points you would like to find or is it just a subset to demostrate the points you are looking for?

Comment: Try search for papers containing the terms "image", "saddle", "detection".

Comment: @kkuilla its just a subset to demonstrate the points I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your images are similar and consistent (no noise, affine transformation) then the following might work.

1. Cut out manually a sample of that patch to be highlighted.
2. Use a [window sliding(template)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) image matching technique to get other similar patches.